# Join multiple mysql tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables in a database: `makers`, `parts`, `transfers`.

`Makers` is
`makerid,stampname`

`Parts` is
`categories,name`

`variations` is
`id, provider, recipient, part`

`Provider` is a pointer to `makers/makerid` and so is `recipients`.

I need to query so that my result shows the friendly name versus the coded/simplified database ids.

I've tried several of the joins but my query:

```
select makers.stampname as giver, makers.stampname as takers
from makers
   left join variations prov on prov.provider=makers.makerid
   left join variations recp on recp.recipient=makers.makerid limit 5;
```

yields the same name in both columns.  If the `provider` is `makerid` 24 and the `recipient` is `makerid` 10, how do I get a query to respond with the coinciding `stampname` from the `makers` db?

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, looks like it was a matter of needing to understand aliasing better.  This worked perfectly:

```
select variations.date,provider.stampname as provname ,
recipient.stampname as recipname, 
parts.name from variations 
left outer join 
makers provider on variations.provider = provider.makerid 
left outer join 
makers recipient on variations.recipient = recipient.makerid
left join categories parts on variations.part = parts.catid 
where variations.provider = "20" 
and 
variations.date="1944";
```